# Set file association from batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, file-association

I want to set file association from a batch file. I want to associate .pdf files with foxitreader. The thing is I have the foxitreader portable edition so it doesn not have any registry key. I have searched but there is no clean explanation of how to do and what syntaxes to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using batch, use the following commands:

```
ftype Foxit.Document=<replace with foxit full path name>
assoc .pdf=Foxit.Document
```

But it could be more convenient to use "Open with", "Select program" and "Always use this program".