# Choose a program that windows will go open files with special format by batch-file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, registry, file-association

(sorry by the english)

I have a app that uses the following command to open files:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(caminhoArquivo));
```

the problem is that i uses a special format to open files (ex.: .TXZ), and if i don´t open the file before by S.O. and says that i want to open that file whit notepad, the app just give a Excption and don´t open..

I´m needing to install this by command like .bat, and add in the registry of windows that i want to open this files in format .XXX by notepad..

Searching here, i found this examples:

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.TXZ
Value: <default> = “TXZ.Document”

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TXZ.Document
Value: <default> = “TXZ Document”

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TXZ.Document\DefaultIcon
Value: <default> = “[!notepad.exe],0?

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TXZ.Document\shell\open\command
Value: <default> = “[!notepad.exe]” “%1?
```

and this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\blergcorp.blergapp.v1\shell\open\command]
@="c:\path\to\app.exe \"%1\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.blerg]
@="blergcorp.blergapp.v1"
```

but how is the first time that i uses something like this, i can´t do my .bat looking like this works.. someone can help me with one example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set file association from batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553040/set-file-association-from-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in batch to open files *.xxx with notepad, use 
`assoc .xxx=txtfile`
(you know, that *.txt opens with notepad and you can peek with `assoc .txt`)
To "un-assoc" use `assoc .xxx=`

Answer (score 0):

```
assoc .txz=TXZfile
assoc TXZfile=TXZfile
ftype TXZfile="%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" "%1"
```

Comment: after i execute this batch-file, the windows show me the message: "Is not possible to locate the file .txt. You wish create a new file?" and don´t open my file.. what is wrong?